# Is the set $W = \{ f(x) \in P(F): f(x)= 0$ or $f(x)$ has degree $n \}$ a subspace of $P(F)$ if $n \geq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the set $W = \{ f(x) \in P(F): f(x)= 0 $ or $f(x)$ has degree $n \} $a subspace of $P(F)$ if n $\geq 1$?

How am I supposed to argue for this? 
My thoughts are suppose $f(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}$ for $x \in W$. condition 1 for subspace is definitely satisfied.  How am I supposed to argue it is closed under addition? Provide an example (or a counterexample)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = x^n + x^{n-1}$ and $g(x) = -x^n$ are both polynomials in $\textsf W$. Are $(f+g)(x)$ in $\textsf W$?